# How can I convert LazyFilterSequence<Results<Element>> to type Results<Element>

Tags: swift, collections, realm

I have a filtered realm object which returns `LazyFilterSequence<Results<Element>>`. I need to use it as `Results<Element>`.
Is there any way to convert it. Why it returns LazyFilterSequence.

items object type is `Results<Element>` and filterList object type is `Object`.

```
let filters = filterList.menuOptions
        .compactMap { $0.isSelected ? NSPredicate(format: "\($0.filter) == 1") : nil }
    
let filtered = items.filter { item in
        //check whether item matches all filters
    if Array(filters).contains(where: { !$0.evaluate(with: item) }) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@dávid-pásztor is right - it is not possible.

you need to use filter with predicate to get Results.

for example:

```
let predicates: [NSPredicate] = filterList.menuOptions
    .filter { $0.isSelected }
    .map { NSPredicate(format: "\($0.filter) == 1") }
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
let filtered = items.filter(predicate)
```

Comment: Forgive me but does this code work? Assuming filterList.menuOptions is an array. I believe that as soon as you implement Swift filtering `.filter { $0.isSelected }` on a Realm Collection, it's going to disconnect the objects from Realm and will not result in Results object. But, I maybe reading it wrong...

Comment: seems like `filterList.menuOptions` is simple array, so we can use simple Swift filter. but `.filter(predicate)` is for Realm Collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `Results` cannot be manually instantiated, since it's an auto-updating collection that can only be instantiated via a Realm query.

You need to use Realm's `filter` if you need the auto-updating nature of `Results`. If Realm's filter doesn't suit your needs and hence you need to use Swift's closure-based `filter`, then you need to sacrifice the auto-updating nature of `Results` and manually rerun your filtering every time the original `Results` is updated.